# Is there any callback when user apply the subscription InAppPurchases?

Tags: android, google-play

I have implemented the subscription flow according to the official guide. But is it possible to get the subscription information when the user Confirmed it on side of the Google Api? Because here it is void and nothing returns. How I can get an access to that transaction?

```
private void startConnection(String type) {

        //Call newBuilder() to create an instance of BillingClient You must also call setListener()
        //passing a reference to a PurchasesUpdatedListener to receive updates on purchases initiated
        // by your app, as well as those initiated by the Google Play Store.
        BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();

        billingClient.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS);
        billingClient.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS_UPDATE);
        //Establish a connection to Google Play. The setup process is asynchronous, and you must
        //implement a BillingClientStateListener to receive a callback once the setup of the client
        //is complete and it’s ready to make further requests.

        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                String s = billingResult.getDebugMessage();
                String ss = String.valueOf(billingResult.getResponseCode());
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    //specifies a list of product ID strings and a SkuType
                    List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
                    skuList.add(type);
//                    skuList.add("vip");
                    SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
                    //IMPORTANT The SkuType can be either SkuType.INAPP for one-time products or SkuType.SUBS for subscriptions
                    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
                    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                            new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                                                                 List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                                    // Process the result.
                                    //Retrieving a product’s price is an important step before a user can purchase a product because
                                    // the price is different for each user based on their country of origin.
                                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
                                        for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                                            String sku = skuDetails.getSku();
                                            String price = skuDetails.getPrice();
                                            BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                                    .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0))
                                                    .build();
                                            billingClient.launchBillingFlow(RewardVideoActivity.this, flowParams);
                                        }
                                    }


                                }
                            });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                String s = "error";
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the calls to  billingClient.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS);
        billingClient.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.SUBSCRIPTIONS_UPDATE);
       work before the client makes a connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call back result comes in interface `PurchasesUpdatedListener` implementation

`onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> list)`